# Could not open JPA EntityManager first time try connect

Tags: java, mysql, database, connection

I have a Javaspring project on azure, this connect to Maria DB Database (Another hosting),

In the Swagger, when I execute a Api Call, returns this error (The second try it's works, but after 10 minutes, fail again the first time)

```
Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

Looking the logs file, I see this error

```
Failed to validate connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@10caecb6 (No operations allowed after connection closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
```

My config file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://database
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

# HikariCP
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=name-pool
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=20000
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=0
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: i guess closed connection threads are still in the pool. There is no information about idle-timeout : 0 property. Maybe you can set some or use default value.

Comment: https://cljdoc.org/d/hikari-cp/hikari-cp/2.13.0/doc/readme

Comment: Still failing with setting value